# Store the result in the variable

Tags: java, arrays, variables, integer, modulo

Store the result in the variable

How do I store the result of **number % 4 = 0** in a variable?
Like this: **number1 = (number2 % 4 = 0)**

Comment: Hint: I suspect the "=" in there is meant to be "checking for equality" rather than "assignment". So, how do you normally check for equality in Java?...

Comment: Just in case. Do not confuse `=` with `==`.

Comment: An obvious mistake by me. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure what do you want exactly. Here are some hints for you:

```java
int quotient  = divisor / divider;               
int remainder = divisor % divider;   
boolean isDivisibleByFour = number % 4 == 0;    //  true or false
```

Comment: An obvious mistake by me. Thank you! I confused = and ==